# PHP if/else based on numerical value

Tags: php

I was able to successfully create the following php mathematical equation using a value derived earlier in a MYSQL query.  This works great except for when the value for $sum_total is below 200, in that case I need to show $sum_total as 0 instead of the value under 200 after subtraction.  What is the best way to handle this?

```
$first_number = $row['PriceAverage'];
$second_number = 200;
$sum_total = $first_number - $second_number;
```

Comment: Unable to understand the question. Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: Yes, please improve!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add after the last line:

```
if ($sum_total < 200) $sum_total = 0;
```

Comment: Not sure why they closed this...your answer was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A simple `if` statement will do the job:

```
if ($sum_total < 0) $sum_total = 0;
```